# FloatingActionMenu not show in xmlLyout android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I implement FloatingActionMenu in my Android project but in my layout the Ui was not shown but if i run my application it shown in real device
i got below Error while layout designing

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:364)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3788)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3892)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:677)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:667)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:663)
at com.github.clans.fab.Label.<init>(Label.java:52)
at com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu.addLabel(FloatingActionMenu.java:481)
at com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu.createLabels(FloatingActionMenu.java:463)
at com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu.onFinishInflate(FloatingActionMenu.java:451)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:844)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:229)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:359)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

below i mentioned my layout:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000">
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
    fab:menu_labels_position="right"
    fab:menu_fab_size="mini"
    fab:menu_openDirection="down">

      <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/infofab"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="Info" />

     <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sharefab"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="Share" />

     <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/favfab"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="Favourite"
        />

   </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
   <!--<TextView
    android:id="@+id/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="#80000000"/>-->
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your java files also

Comment: what is at line 364 in ViewConfiguration.java class ?

Comment: if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) return;
        final Label label = new Label(mLabelsContext);
        label.setClickable(true);@AmitVaghela